# Is there a way to find the log ERROR patterns in Bitbucket code repository

Tags: java, logging, error-handling, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repo that contains the Java codes and the developers have embedded different patterns of the logs [ERROR, CRITICAL, INFO] in the code to be thrown when a specific exception/issue is hit.
Now I am trying to find all those log patterns one by one from the code which is a long-lasting tedious task.

Is there any way to solve this use case in an automated way?

For example:, like upload a code to a specific app or solution and it tells you that there are 10 CRITICAL log patterns, 15 ERROR log patterns, and 20 INFO log patterns in a particular bitbucket code repository.